# Definition of submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ a matrix, I need the definition of sub matrix of $A$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try our dear friend [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Submatrix).

Elaboration, as requested.  Let $A\in M_{m,n}$ have $m$ rows and $n$ columns.  Set $S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, m\}$, $T\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, such that both $S,T$ are nonempty.

We name these elements as $S=\{s_1, s_2,\ldots, s_{|S|}\}, T=\{t_1,t_2,\ldots, t_{|T|}\}$, and assume that $s_1<s_2<\cdots<s_{|S|}$ and $t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_{|T|}$.

Then we define submatrix $B$ via $$(B)_{i,j}=(A)_{s_i,t_j}$$